# Regex Get AccessToken in Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to get access token by regex from below string:

access_token=**CAABletmsJHgBAEMfdJEgA1wEXgqwVgfM1nrTgyHq9XxkIEvLVGOUMq80ZBaA2ZA6Ndc18xNwZAJCDwpILNSKgGiVu4SIm9Bas5ocv7ZCVFV1bxKrNW9qrIqK1HKIz3uD6nO4RQnVgfVmLggoqZCVkPwjEY79ijZC0SYKPYM2RN9qg4TZB5E2iMz5WfAAACddAbXaEZCbzkBSoSZBTlEyea8rC**&expires=5181509

I want a pattern matches casual position of *expires* and *access_token* in the provided string.

I am newbie in regex and my pattern does not work very well

```
access_token=(.*?)&expires=\d+
```

Can you help me, please?

https://regex101.com/r/oS4xE5/1

Comment: What's the problem with result? Don't you only need a second pair of parenthesis:    access_token=(.*?)&expires=(\d+)

Comment: your regex is kind of ok(no need for the ? after the *), you just need to capture the group

Comment: paste the output you expect from the string given?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "lookarounds" with the following idiom:

```
String input = "access_token=CAABletmsJHgBAEMfdJEgA1wEXgqwVgfM1nr" +
    "TgyHq9XxkIEvLVGOUMq80ZBaA2ZA6Ndc18xNwZAJCDwpILNSKgGiVu4SIm9B" +
    "as5ocv7ZCVFV1bxKrNW9qrIqK1HKIz3uD6nO4RQnVgfVmLggoqZCVkPwjEY79" +
    "ijZC0SYKPYM2RN9qg4TZB5E2iMz5WfAAACddAbXaEZCbzkBSoSZBTlEyea8rC" +
    "&expires=5181509";
//                           ┌ preceded by "access_token"
//                           |                 ┌ anything reluctantly quantified 
//                           |                 |  ┌ followed by "&"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=access_token=).+?(?=&)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
CAABletmsJHgBAEMfdJEgA1wEXgqwVgfM1nrTgyHq9XxkIEvLVGOUMq80ZBaA2ZA6Ndc18xNwZAJCDwpILNSKgGiVu4SIm9Bas5ocv7ZCVFV1bxKrNW9qrIqK1HKIz3uD6nO4RQnVgfVmLggoqZCVkPwjEY79ijZC0SYKPYM2RN9qg4TZB5E2iMz5WfAAACddAbXaEZCbzkBSoSZBTlEyea8rC
```

**Note**

This will validate less than what you're matching with your current pattern as it only fetches what's between `access_token=` and `&`.

Comment: hi, I could have this situation access_token=CAABletmsJHgBAEMfdJEgA1wEXgqwVgfM1nr" +
    "TgyHq9XxkIEvLVGOUMq80ZBaA2ZA6Ndc18xNwZAJCDwpILNSKgGiVu4SIm9B" +
    "as5ocv7ZCVFV1bxKrNW9qrIqK1HKIz3uD6nO4RQnVgfVmLggoqZCVkPwjEY79" +
    "ijZC0SYKPYM2RN9qg4TZB5E2iMz5WfAAACddAbXaEZCbzkBSoSZBTlEyea8rC      without    &expires=5181509     . Can you update the regex, please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why that regex wouldn't work apart from that '\' has to be escaped in Java, as such:

```
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile("access_token=(.*?)&expires=\\d+");
     Matcher m = p.matcher("access_token=CAABletmsJHgBAEMfdJEgA1wEXgqwVgfM1nrTgyHq9XxkIEvLVGOUMq80ZBaA2ZA6Ndc18xNwZAJCDwpILNSKgGiVu4SIm9Bas5ocv7ZCVFV1bxKrNW9qrIqK1HKIz3uD6nO4RQnVgfVmLggoqZCVkPwjEY79ijZC0SYKPYM2RN9qg4TZB5E2iMz5WfAAACddAbXaEZCbzkBSoSZBTlEyea8rC&expires=5181509");
     if (m.find()) {
         System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

**Output**

> CAABletmsJHgBAEMfdJEgA1wEXgqwVgfM1nrTgyHq9XxkIEvLVGOUMq80ZBaA2ZA6Ndc18xNwZAJCDwpILNSKgGiVu4SIm9Bas5ocv7ZCVFV1bxKrNW9qrIqK1HKIz3uD6nO4RQnVgfVmLggoqZCVkPwjEY79ijZC0SYKPYM2RN9qg4TZB5E2iMz5WfAAACddAbXaEZCbzkBSoSZBTlEyea8rC